# R - select and assign value to group based on condition in column

Tags: r

Having a data frame that looks like the following:

```
d
   year  pos  days   sal
1  2009  A     31   2000
2  2009  B     60   4000
3  2009  C     10    600
4  2010  B     10   1000
5  2010  D     90   7000
```

I would like to group data by `year`, adding `days` and `sal`, and select `pos` where `days` is maximum in the group.

The result should be like:

```
  year   pos  days   sal
1 2009    B    101   6600
2 2010    D    100   8000
```

I could deal with numeric values such as `days` and `sal` using functions like `tapply(d$days, d$year, sum)`.

However, I have no idea how I can select pos that meets a condition on days and assign it to the group.

Any comments will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use dput(nameofdataframe) and post that in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`.  After grouping by 'year', get the 'pos' where the 'days' are max (`which.max(days)`), as well do the `sum` of 'days' and 'sal'.

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(pos = pos[which.max(days)], days = sum(days), sal = sum(sal))
# # A tibble: 2 × 4
#   year   pos  days   sal
#  <int> <chr> <int> <int>
#1  2009     B   101  6600
#2  2010     D   100  8000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was looking for this :)

Answer (score 1):

A solution with base R:

```
m1 <- d[as.logical(with(d, ave(days, year, FUN = function(x) seq_along(x) == which.max(x))  )), c('year','pos')]
m2 <- aggregate(cbind(days, sal) ~ year, d, sum)

merge(m1, m2, by = 'year')
```

Or with the **data.table** package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)[order(days), .(pos = pos[.N], days = sum(days), sal = sum(sal)), by = year]
```

the resulting data.frame / data.table:

```
  year pos days  sal
1 2009   B  101 6600
2 2010   D  100 8000
```

Answer (score 0):

With sqldf:

```
library(sqldf)
cbind.data.frame(sqldf('select year, sum(days) as days, sum(sal) as sal 
                        from d group by year'),
                 sqldf('select pos from d group by year having days=max(days)'))


  year days  sal pos
1 2009  101 6600   B
2 2010  100 8000   D
```

Comment: This also works: `sqldf("select year, pos, max(days) max_days, sum(days) days, sum(sal) sal from d group by year")`